# Characteristics of 'true' tissue

Tags: zoology, tissue

Why are sponges not considered to have tissue level organization?

Quite a few places seem to say that sponges do not have 'true tissue' and only have specialized cells.

> Unlike Protozoans, the Poriferans are multicellular. However, unlike higher metazoans, the cells that make up a sponge are not organized into tissues. Therefore, sponges lack true tissues and organs;

The Wikipedia page on sponges says -

> Sponges are similar to other animals in that they are multicellular, heterotrophic, lack cell walls and produce sperm cells. Unlike other animals, they lack true tissues and organs.

I have not been able to find what defines true tissue, so I would like to understand what characteristics a group of cells must have for it to be considered proper tissue.

Comment: Can you please expand your question with at least one quote from a source that uses the term "true tissue", in order to help understand your question? When I google, the term I find is "organized tissue", which may be different than you are asking about.

Comment: @jakebeal I'm so sorry, I don't really know how you add a quote from a source. However, true tissue is what showed up on multiple pages when I googled 'Do sponges have tissues and organs?'

Comment: Is this the definition you mean https://glossary.lias.net/wiki/True_tissue ?

Comment: @ani You can edit your question and add text from one of the sources that you saw.  To indicate a quote, you can just use quotation marks or do a ">" for a blockquote.

Comment: @jakebeal thank you! I've edited the question, hope it is clearer now.